# ASP MVC nuget packages are not added to the correct folders

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nuget

I've added two well known projects to an ASP MVC application and it looks like the packages don't install under `/Scripts` and `/Content` as expected (CSS and JS are bundled together).

Am I missing something? Do package authors assume that people will move content to the correct folders, or does no one use the default ASP MVC template folders?

E.g.

[image]

[image]

Comment: If all package files were added directly under the Scripts and Content folders, you could end up with hundreds of files (with possible naming conflicts) making it difficult to manage. You can just specify the path in your bundles or script/link tags rather than moving the files to the top level folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am I missing something?

Nope.

> Do package authors assume that people will move content to the correct folders, or does no one use the default ASP MVC template folders?

Pretty much both.

There is no guarantee that packages will properly conform to the default ASP.NET MVC template.

The authors have probably done it because

- As a standalone project, it makes logical sense to put them in such a folder structure.
- The project may be trying to be generic across many platforms. In this case it doesn't fit with MVC too well.

Comment: Cool. Thanks. Any advice on how to proceed in my situation? Split JS/CSS as the template suggests, or move all "Content" under the same folder.

Comment: I'm inclined to just keep them in their own folders and modify bundles accordingly. It might save trouble if you update or reinstall packages.